# Redirecting output to a file in linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-communication

i am writing a c program, that sets up serial communication between a Raspberry PI (Debian Wheezy) and a modem. The program works so far but i want the output also to be redirected in a .txt or .csv file.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <termios.h> 

#define MODEM "/dev/ttyUSB0" 
#define BAUDRATE B9600     

int main(int argc,char** argv) 
{    
struct termios tio; 
struct termios stdio; 
struct termios old_stdio; 
int tty_fd, flags; 
unsigned char c='D'; 
tcgetattr(STDOUT_FILENO,&old_stdio); 
printf("Starte bitte %s /dev/ttyUSB0\n",argv[0]); 
memset(&stdio,0,sizeof(stdio)); 
stdio.c_iflag=0; 
stdio.c_oflag=0; 
stdio.c_cflag=0; 
stdio.c_lflag=0; 
stdio.c_cc[VMIN]=1; 
stdio.c_cc[VTIME]=0; 
tcsetattr(STDOUT_FILENO,TCSANOW,&stdio); 
tcsetattr(STDOUT_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&stdio); 
fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);       // make the reads non-blocking 
memset(&tio,0,sizeof(tio)); 
tio.c_iflag=0; 
tio.c_oflag=0; 
tio.c_cflag=CS8|CREAD|CLOCAL;           // 8n1, see termios.h for more information 
tio.c_lflag=0; 
tio.c_cc[VMIN]=1; 
tio.c_cc[VTIME]=5; 
if((tty_fd = open(MODEM , O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK)) == -1){ 
    printf("Error while opening\n"); // Just if you want user interface error control 
    return -1; 
} 
cfsetospeed(&tio,BAUDRATE);     
cfsetispeed(&tio,BAUDRATE);            // baudrate is declarated above 
tcsetattr(tty_fd,TCSANOW,&tio); 
while (c!='q'){ 
    if (read(tty_fd,&c,1)>0){ 
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,&c,1); // if new data is available on the serial port, print it out 
        printf(""); 
    } 
    if (read(STDIN_FILENO,&c,1)>0){ 
        write(tty_fd,&c,1);//if new data is available on the console, send it to serial port 
        printf(""); 
    } 
} 
close(tty_fd); 
tcsetattr(STDOUT_FILENO,TCSANOW,&old_stdio); 
return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Hopefully there is one who can help me

Answer (score 1):

why not do that outside of your program?

the following will write the (std)output of your program into the file `foo.txt`:

```
./myprogram > foo.txt
```

if you also want to see the output, pipe it through `tee` (which will write it's stdin to stdout *and* a file)

```
./myprogram | tee foo.txt
```

if you are absolutely sure that you want to do all this from within your program, you might want to write your own `write` function, which writes to both `stdout` and a file.

```
ssize_t mywrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count) {
    write(fd, buf, count);
    return write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, count);
}
```

and then use it, instead of `write` (note that you should pass the filedescriptor of an opened file to`mywrite`; it will *also* write to STDOUT)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you don't simply `open()` a new path and `write()` to that instead of writing to stdout. If that's not an option (it appears to be an option, the best one, in your example code), you can perform run-time redirection using this pseudo code.

```
#include <unistd.h>

// first open the new output path
int new_out = open("/path/to/output", flags_as_needed);

// next, move the standard output path
int save_out = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);

// now copy the new output path to the standard output position
dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, new_out);
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it seems not to work. Where in the code shall i insert this? I'm sorry but i'm new to programming maybe you can help me. A new file is created but it doesn't write the output into the file.

Comment: You're having this follow-up failure because the flags you pass to `open()` (_flags_as_needed) are not including writing. For example, this set of flags will work (as long as there aren't other problems with the path you've selected): `O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR`

Answer (score 0):

just open a file and use its file descriptor:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() 
{ 
  char block[1024]; //buffer of data
  int out; //file deccriptor
  int nread; //size of data
  out = open("file.out", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR); 
  write(out,block,nread); 
  exit(0); 
}
```